# how to bind tooltip to L.esri.DynamicMapLayer

Tags: leaflet, esri, esri-leaflet

I can bind a popup to esri leaflet's `L.esri.DynamicMapLayer` layer but how would I bind a tooltip to below `DynamicMapLayer` ?

```
var featureLayer = L.esri.dynamicMapLayer({
        url: url,
        useCors: true
});
```

Comment: like this: http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/customizing-popups.html